# $[G:H]=[K:f(H)]$

Tags: group-theory

Question:

> If $f:G\to K$ is an isomorphism of groups and $H\leq G$ then $[G:H]=[K:f(H)]$

Attempt:

> I have shown that it is true for finite $G,K$ but I'm not sure if a counterexample exists for infinite $G,K$

Comment: Hint: use the fact that $f$ is an isomorphism to show that $C \mapsto f(C)$ is a bijection between the cosets of $H$ in $G$ and the cosets of $f(H)$ in $K$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of the all-important Correspondence theorem. Suppose $\;\{x_i\}_{i\in I}\;$ is a complete, non-redundant set of representatives of the left cosets of $\;H\;$ in G, meaning:

$$(*)\;\;G=\bigcup_{i\in I}x_iH\;,\;\text{and for any $\;\emptyset\neq J\subset I\,$, we have that}\;\;\bigcup_{j\in J}x_jH\neq G$$

Now look at $\;\left\{fx_i\right\}_{i\in I}\;$. Since$\,(*)\,$ , we have that

$$K\stackrel{f\,\text{ is onto}}=f(G)=f\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}x_iH\right)=\bigcup_{i\in I}f(x_iH)=\bigcup_{i\in I}fx_if(H)$$

Suppose now that there exist $\;i,j\in I\;$ s.t. for $\;k\in K\;$ :

$$k\in fx_if(H)\cap fx_jf(H)\implies \exists\,h_1,h_2\in H\;\;s.t\;\; x=fx_ifh_1=fx_jfh_2$$

But $\;f\;$ is a group homomorphism, thus the last equality is exactly the same as

$$f(x_ih_1)=f(x_jh_2)\iff\left(x_jh_2\right)^{-1}x_ih_1\in\ker f=1 \text{ (since $\,f\,$ is 1-1 !)}\implies$$

$$x_ih_1=x_jh_2\iff x_iH=x_jH\iff i=j$$

Fill in last details...